# How interact with dcc.DatePickerSingle using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, testing, plotly-dash

I am testing a dashboard created with dash and I have a couple of dcc.DatePickerSingle. I want to test these by introducing some dates and then also test that the result generated by the dashboard is equal to the expected value.

I show the code I am using

```
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep


URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/'
@pytest.fixture
def browser():
  # Initialize ChromeDriver
  driver = Chrome("./chromedriver")
  # Wait implicitly for elements to be ready before attempting interactions
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  
  # Return the driver object at the end of setup
  yield driver
  
  # For cleanup, quit the driver
  driver.quit()

def test_dates(browser):
  browser.get(URL)
  data_start ="Hola"
  search_input1 = browser.find_element_by_id('my-date-picker-start')
  search_input1.send_keys(data_start)
```

The error I got after many different attend is

```
ElementNotInteractableException
```

To run this the command is `pipenv run python -m pytest`

Is this element not iterable (I douth that) or I am doing something wrong (Very likely)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use explicit wait rather than implicit wait.
So, remove `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` (and never use it until you are clearly understand how implicit wait works) and try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

search_input1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "my-date-picker-start")))

search_input1.send_keys(data_start)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I delete ```driver.implicitly_wait(10)``` all tests failed. Second, your code reported the error ´driver´ is not defined. I have tried ```browser (driver, 20)...```  but the same error was found.

Comment: Sure, you still have to define driver as previously. The only code line I asked to remove is driver.implicitly_wait(10) since implicit wait doesn't work correctly with explicit wait.
The first 3 imports should be on the top of the class, where you have other imports already.

Comment: I am going to show you in a google doc the complete code and you are allowed to edit https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YK4_ubC-d02nLJcYKXL1Bp95yH18K9zqahhwKIEqkKs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I saw that, thanks, but I don't want to edit your code. It's your work to do this. For the simplest verification if what I suggested is correct you can add a simple sleep(5) before search_input1 = browser.find_element_by_id('my-date-picker-start'). Please let me know if now it works better

Comment: Many thank, with search_input1 = browser.find_element_by_id('my-date-picker-start') the test pass but then what I dont know is to interact with the element